# Can't export database from phpMyadmin on Xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried to export a WordPress database from Xampp's phpMyAdmin, but suddenly this error shows up:

*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Export::getFilenameAndMimetype() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php on line 380 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php:270 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php(380): PhpMyAdmin\Export->getFilenameAndMimetype('database', '', Object(PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportSql), '', NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php on line 270*

I tried cleaning the cache from the dev tools of the browser, but the issue hasn't been solved. Besides, as soon as I click on "Export", I see a message about one form having more than 1000 lines.

I successfully exported the database with the command line, following another solution found here at StackOverflow, but I need to deselect a couple of tables, which is why I'd rather use the "usual" way.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what, in my case, solved the issue.
Open the Xampp's php.ini file and paste the following at the bottom:

```
max_input_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
```

Save the file and restart Apache from Xampp.

Comment: doing, max_input_vars = 5000 works for me. thanks Pen061.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what worked for me when I was exporting a table,**

1. While you export you will find Quick is selected,
2. you need to select custom, then
3. go to Output section and do the following
4. select, save output to file
5. on compression category, select zipped

Then go on download your table as a zipped file.